# how to expand canvas window to fill the full size window in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am new to Tkinter, I am trying to create a full-screen scrollable frame using Tkinter and canvas. here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Learn To Code at Codemy.com')
root.geometry("500x400")


def FrameWidth(event):
    canvas_width = event.width
    canvas_height = event.height

    my_canvas.itemconfig(canvas_frame, width = canvas_width)
    # my_canvas.itemconfig(canvas_frame, height = canvas_height)
    # my_canvas.itemconfig(canvas_frame, width = canvas_width, height = canvas_height)



def OnFrameConfigure(event):
    my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all"))

# Create A Main Frame
main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)



# Create A Canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame, bg='red')
my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
my_canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
my_canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Create ANOTHER Frame INSIDE the Canvas
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas, bg='blue')


# Add that New frame To a Window In The Canvas
canvas_frame = my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")




# Add A Scrollbar To The Canvas
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)


main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=5)
main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)


# Configure The Canvas
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', FrameWidth)
second_frame.bind('<Configure>', OnFrameConfigure)




for thing in range(5):
    Button(second_frame, text=f'Button {thing} Yo!').grid(row=thing, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky = 'news')

my_label = Label(second_frame, text="It's Friday Yo!").grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='news')

second_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=4)
second_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)



root.mainloop()
```

my problem is that the frame with a blue background does not expand to full size and fill the canvas window, here is a screenshot of my app, my question is how to expand the second frame to fill entire window:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JBLv.png)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need it to fill the canvas? Why not just give it the same background color as the canvas so that it blends in?

Comment: The entire point of using a Canvas is that it's *not* bound to another widgets size. This is what makes it scrollable. You need add the code yourself to detect changes in the Canvas width and pass that along to the Frame. This will mean that you also need to calculate and set the Frame height, since a tkinter Frame can only automatically do both or neither.

Comment: If you make the size of the internal frame same as the canvas, you lost the feature of scrollable frame.